# Making up groups of Coins

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

In how many ways can a group of 100 coins be made up from 50,20,10,5,2 or 1 coin(s) respectively?

An alternative way of phrasing this would be how many ways can a group of 100 coins be made from choosing coins of value 50,20,10,5,2,1?
I have tried the problem, and I've realised it is quite difficult to keep track of the arrangements checked (I know the answer is around 4000 though). Can this be solved without a computer?

Comment: To clarify, I mean how many ways can a group of 100 coins be made from choosing coins of value 50,20,10,5,2,1?

Comment: this problem is a lot nicer on computer.

Comment: @above: How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a generating function. For pennies, we can have $1, 2, ..., $ selections. So we have the generating function $f_{1}(x) = 1 + x + x^{2} + ... = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Similarly, with two-cent pieces, we have $f_{2}(x) = 1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + ... = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{2i} = \frac{1}{1-x^{2}}$. We continue this pattern to get the generating function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^{5}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^{10}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^{20}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^{50}}$$

You then would want to use something like a computer algebra system to expand out searching for the coefficient of $x^{100}$. Of course, you could theoretically do it by hand, but it would be tedious to do.

**Edit**: Generating functions work by using a formal geometric series to index terms. So $x^{0}$ says you have none of that term while $x^{53}$ says you have $53$ units. I am using them here to count the number of each coin. Pennies count one unit each, so $f_{1}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i}$ counts the number of pennies you have. In contrast, the five cent pieces count as five units of money. So we have: $f_{5}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{5i}$.

By rule of product, we multiply each function together to get the main generating function. We then use geometric series identities to expand out the terms and seek the coefficient of $x^{100}$, which is your desired monetary amount.

This article provides a good look at generating functions too, at least to help conceptualize for you: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/304589-a-look-at-the-knapsack-problem-with-generating-functions/

Comment: How does the generating function work? I have seen this before but do not understand it? Forgive my ignorance please

Comment: Where would the coefficient of x^100 come from?

Comment: Wait- you want 100 coins, not a dollar (or pound, as I think you said you were British)? I may have misread your question then. If you want 100 coins, this would be stars and bars.

Comment: No, the pound is right. Not stars and bars. Thanks for your answer, and sorry if I'm missing something, but upon multiplying out don't you only get an $ x^88 $ term

Comment: Does "100 coins" mean, say in USA, "100 cents"?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make the problem more universal, since I figured not everyone on here is from Britain...

Comment: @Kinhu No. You have $(1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + ...) \cdot (1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + ....) \cdot (1 + x^{5} + x^{10} + ...)$. And you continue out. We let the series go out to infinity, and we only look at terms of interest. We use geometric series identities to simplify.

Comment: Seeing as I have nothing to do, I'm going to expand it out to get the answer by hand, too see how long it will take. Any tip on how to go out it before I plunge straight in

Comment: You could try plugging it in on WolframAlpha or Mathematica. That's the route I'd go. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find an algorithm to solve the problem that is more efficient than the one for computer which goes like this. You want to find the positive integer solutions to the equation $100a+50b+20c+10d+5e+2f\leq 100$ (Luckily we can simplify the problem slightly because we have $1$ which can take any previous coins up to exactly $100$.

I wrote this code in java, I hope it helps(take into account I just learned to program two weeks ago). Also the code takes into account 200 dollar coins and 100 dollar coins, and it wants to add 200 instead of 100.

public class prob31 {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,s=0;
    for(a=0;a<=1;a++){
        for(b=0;b<=(200-200*a-((200-200*a)%100))/100;b++){
            for(c=0;c<=(200-200*a-100*b-((200-200*a-100*b)%50))/50;c++){
                for(d=0;d<=(200-200*a-100*b-50*c-((200-200*a-100*b-50*c)%20))/20;d++){
                    for(e=0;e<=(200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-((200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d)%10))/10;e++){
                        for(f=0;f<=(200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-10*e-((200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-10*e)%5))/5;f++){
                            for(g=0;g<=(200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-10*e-5*f-((200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-10*e-5*f)%2))/2;g++){
                                s++;
                                System.out.println(200-200*a-100*b-50*c-20*d-10*e-5*f-2*g);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    System.out.println(s);
    }


}
```

Comment: This is certainly cleaner to do with recursion. You can optimize by looking at which denominations divide the remaining amount to save from unnecessarily recursing.

Comment: Oh, that's neat, do you have the code?

Comment: Not readily. I wrote something like this a few years back. The naive approve would be for each denomination, subtract from the amount and recurse. This would count permutations, though. Probably the better way would be to have a List<Integer> of some sort. Focus on the larger denomination. Use as much as you can, then work on the next largest denomination.

Comment: @JorgeFernández http://pastebin.com/nQjNHeDb

Comment: @Jorge There is also an extensive discussion in *Higher-Order Perl* chapter 5, [available here](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/).